# Canvas rect method rounded top right corner

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I draw a rectangle with canvas all the corners are square except for the top right one which has a border radius of what looks like 1 pixel.

How can I make all corners square?

Comment: is the browser zoomed in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *should* do it:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);
```

If not, can you show us the code you're using and an example of the output?